# How to mark a page as a language copy?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, metadata, modern-pages, api, localization

I have a SharePoint Online site, where I need to translate some pages into different target languages. My site's default language is English, thus the source language of a page is always English. The language copies created go into the respective folders (the automatically created folders with the 2-letter language code).

In a few cases, the content was created first in a target language (in a language copy folder) and needs to be translated into English. Using the REST API, a site like this is treated as source language content.

```
{
  "_SPIsTranslation": "No",
  "_SPIsTranslation.value": "0",
  "_SPTranslatedLanguages": ["nl-nl", "fi-fi", "de-de", "fr-fr"],
  "_SPTranslationLanguage": "",
  "_SPTranslationSourceItemId": ""
}
```

Is there a way to change these metadata, in order to have the specific page as a language copy?
Or any other options so that the translated page is recognized as a translation (and it can be selected in the language selection dropdown)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this blog post answers my question:
https://www.eliostruyf.com/linking-unlinking-multilingual-pages-sharepoint/